# How to stop Home Range Plots from Plotting on Top of Each Other

Tags: r

I have a list of annual telemetry objects for several individuals. I also have a loop to calculate KDE home ranges. I'm having trouble plotting my home range estimates. My loop to plot the KDE home ranges results in all individual home ranges for a given year being plotted onto the same figure. What I'd like to do is have each individual home range plotted as its own plot for each year. I've included an example of my code below using buffalo data from the ctmm package:

```
library(ctmm) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr) 
library(lubridate) 
library(sf) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(sp) 
library(scales) 
library(tidyr) 
library(tibble)

#Load the data
data("buffalo")

#Creating individual dataframes and adding an id column
Cilla <- as.data.frame(buffalo$Cilla) 
Cilla$id<-"Cilla"

Gabs<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Gabs)
Gabs$id<-"Gabs"

Mvubu<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Mvubu)
Mvubu$id<-"Mvubu"

Pepper<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Pepper)
Pepper$id<-"Pepper"

Queen<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Queen)
Queen$id<-"Queen"

Toni<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Toni)
Toni$id<-"Toni"

#Combining dataframes and adding a year, UTM zone, and date column
buffalo2 <- rbind(Cilla,Gabs,Mvubu,Pepper,Queen,Toni)
buffalo2$Year<-year(buffalo2$timestamp)
buffalo2$Year<-as.factor(buffalo2$Year)
buffalo2$UTM.zone<-"12 +datum=NAD27"
buffalo2$timestamp <- ymd_hms(buffalo2$timestamp) 
buffalo2$Timestamp<-buffalo2$timestamp
buffalo2 <- separate(buffalo2, timestamp, c("date","time"), sep= " ", remove= TRUE, extra= "merge")

#Reordering columns
buffalo2 <- buffalo2[, c(8,9,1,2,6,7,11,10)]

#Splitting data by year
data2005<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2005)
data2006<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2006)

#Creating annual telemetry data
Tdata2005<-as.telemetry(data2005, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
                        timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                        na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)
Tdata2006<-as.telemetry(data2006, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
                        timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                        na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)

#Creating a list of telemetry data
Tdata<-list(Tdata2005,Tdata2006)
names(Tdata)<-c("Tdata2005","Tdata2006")

#Function to calculate KDE ranges
HRKDE <- function(x,date) {
  KDE<-list()
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  {
    print(i)
    M.IID <- ctmm.fit(x[[i]])
    KDE[[i]] <- akde(x[[i]],M.IID, units=FALSE)
  }
  return(KDE)
}

#Applying the HRKDE function to the telemetry data
KDEs <- lapply(seq_along(Tdata), function(i) HRKDE(Tdata[[i]]))

#adding names
for (i in 1:length(KDEs)) {    
  names(KDEs)<-names(Tdata)
  names(KDEs[[i]])<-names(Tdata[[i]])
}

#Loop to plot KDEs
for(i in 1:length(KDEs)){
  plot(KDEs[[i]])
  
}
```

This code is able to calculate KDE home range estimates, but it plots all home ranges for a given year on top of each other. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!